# Uninitialized constant Error using ActiveMerchant::Billing::EwayManagedGateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I'm trying to get a small ruby file up and running to test how the EwayManagedGateway works.

I'm looking at using Eway to store a users credit card details so I don't need to store them in the site db.

Here is the documentation for EwayManagedGateway

http://rdoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/master/ActiveMerchant/Billing/EwayManagedGateway

I've created a simple ruby file to test this.

```
require "rubygems"
require "activemerchant"

ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::EwayManagedGateway.new(
:login => '99999999',
:username => 'myusername',
:password => 'password'
)
```

I've based this code on what is supplied in the standard eway documentation which works.

http://rdoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/master/ActiveMerchant/Billing/EwayGateway

Here's the output error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::EwayManagedGateway
at top level    in managed_payments.rb at line 6
Program exited with code #1 after 0.26 seconds.
```

I'm running Rails 3 and activemerchant 1.12.1

Docs on github specific to eway_managed payments.
https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/eway_managed.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of my problem was related to me using activemerchant gem 1.11.0. Once I upgraded my gem to 1.15.0 I didn't have the error any further.

Comment: I am happy your issue got fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Should this be require 'active_merchant' instead of require "activemerchant" according to docs http://rdoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/master/ActiveMerchant/Billing/EwayGateway

Comment: Doesn't work even if I use their entire example but thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Actually the point you raised is interesting considering I'm using an activemerchant gem while there is also an active_merchant gem. Not sure why there is two similar gems.

Comment: http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/586-activemerchant-and-active_merchant according to this there are these 2 variants of activemerchant gems that basically do the same thing.but in your case I think its the active_merchant gem that needs to be installed. Did you try installing the active_merchant gem and uninstalling the activemerchant gem?